# Can't show new added attr in template from object in Queryset in UpdateView (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to output a list of additional model objects that are affected by this main object. The main model doesn't affect the additional one, so I'm trying to add the list to the new object attribute. When I print `.__dict__` of an object after adding a new attribute, everything is OK, but the template outputs a blank.. How do I fix this?

My code in UpdateView:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    print('ID: ', self.kwargs['adapter_account_id'])
    deals = Deal.objects.filter(adapter_account=self.kwargs['adapter_account_id'])
    adapter_acc = AdapterAccount.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['adapter_account_id'])
    for obj in adapter_acc:
        obj.deals = deals
    print(adapter_acc[0].__dict__)
    return adapter_acc
```

Output for `.__dict__`:

```
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7fa0590547c0>, 'id': 13,
'adapter_id': 9, 
'params': {'secret': 'secret', 'pay_gate': 'VV', 'product_id': '10731', 'merchant_id': '1998'}, 
'deals':<QuerySet [<Deal:#28>, <Deal:#30>]>}
```

My try to render value in template:

```
{{ adapteraccount.deals}}
```

For example, `{{ adapteraccount.params}}` works fine.

UPD: `obj.save()` in loop doesn't have any effect.

`QuerySet.update(deals=deals)` doesn't working because the model does not contain this field.

Comment: Shouldn't you save your obj?

Comment: @bartaelterman, I tried to add `obj.save()` in loop now, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: And what about iterating over `deals` in your template and printing some text along with an attribute of the deal? Like `{% for deal in adapteraccount.deals %}Deal: {{deal}}{% endfor %}`

Comment: @bartaelterman blank space

Comment: Sorry, when iterating over the queryset, you should use .all: `{% for deal in adapteraccount.deals.all %}Deal: {{deal}}{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried adding an attribute that is not included in the model even a normal string and nothing worked. So I decided to go the other way and modified render_to_response:

```
  def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
    """
    Return a response, using the `response_class` for this view, with a
    template rendered with the given context.
    Pass response_kwargs to the constructor of the response class.
    """
    deals = Deal.objects.filter(adapter_account=self.kwargs['adapter_account_id'])
    context['deals'] = deals
    response_kwargs.setdefault('content_type', self.content_type)
    return self.response_class(
        request=self.request,
        template=self.get_template_names(),
        context=context,
        using=self.template_engine,
        **response_kwargs
    )
```